# Does staying at a Pokestop too long reduce the number of items you get?

Tags: pokemon-go

I have a great spot in my city where I can sit with 4 overlapping Pokestops. It's great to pop a few Lure's and every 5 minutes collect from 4 stops.

[image]

But I've noticed something.. I seem to *only* get 3 items from each Pokestop every time. Whereas if I was moving around from Pokestop to Pokestop - I would have more variety, at least 4-6 items dropping every once in a while.

Does the length of time you spend at one or more Pokestops decrease the yield of items?

**EDIT:** I'm at 12 [times](https://i.stack.imgur.com/L2xQ5.jpg) in a [row](https://i.stack.imgur.com/m2O8w.jpg) that I've only got 3 items. Really bad luck?

Comment: are you sure is **always** 3 items? is just random, i don think time affect the loot

Comment: @lois6b I'm at 8 times in a row. Going for 12.

Comment: wow, maybe it does affect... later im gonna check out my self

Comment: @lois6b 12 times in a row. Maybe because I don't have any lures going or anything?

Comment: wait, how could you go from 8 times to 12 times in a row in about 4 min?

Comment: @lois6b There's 4 Pokestops lol

Comment: right ^^' my fault

Comment: @lois6b Just did it again and got 3 items at 3 of the 4 stops. So 1 stop gave me 4 items. Still feels lower.. when I was walking around earlier I got 6-8 item stops frequently and now it feels like never.

Comment: bad luck maybe. i didnt stop at the same spot for a while to know for sure ...

Comment: Afaik your level matters as you need to be level 5 to get more than just Pokéballs and eggs. Until then you'll usually get 3 items or sometimes 4. Later you'll get 4 or more items more often, although 3 is still the most common amount.

Comment: @dly I'm level 14

Comment: Then you're probably just unlucky. I've never heard of camping penalty in that particular case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think it matters. There are two overlapping pokéstops at my office and I spin them every 5 minutes, and I still get a completely random number of items. Usually it's three, but I've gotten up to 7 before.